# SEC filings data using API in python with filter for specific strings

Tags: python, edgar, sec

I'm trying to extract SEC filings in a certain date range with a certain key string, for several different companies.

Basically I'm trying to replicate the search in this link:
SEC Edgar (https://www.sec.gov/edgar/search/#)

I installed the required libraries using pip and ran the below code, which gives me all the submissions in a dict format.

```
from sec_edgar_api import EdgarClient

edgar = EdgarClient(user_agent="<Sample Company Name> <Admin Contact>@<Sample Company Domain>")

# Sample CIK
# manual pagination handling
submissions = edgar.get_submissions(cik="104169", handle_pagination=False)
```

However, I'm unable to find the options for filtering by dates and key strings. It would be great if anyone could help me incorporate these options in my search query.

Comment: That page appears to use the endpoint `https://efts.sec.gov/LATEST/search-index?q=foobar&startdt=2018-08-21&enddt=2023-08-21`, which isn't part of their official API.

Comment: Do you have to use EdgarClient? As it is a get request with params in the URL, you can simply user 'requests' package and parse the returned HTML.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, I'm not able to extract the result links using the 'requests' package (get_text or get_url).